# Click event of a button which is subview of an image view in xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimageview, uibutton

in my app i have an image view and above that i added an button.And also in button click event i am calling a method.But i am unable to click on the button .whenever i try to click the button then the row of the table vie win which my image view is present is selected .Is there any method from which i can get the click event of the button which is placed on the image view.I do not want to use UIbuttons for setting the images in place of image view .Also if i am adding button as a subview of the table view then the click event is working but when i change the subview to image view then i get unsatisfactory result.Please help.

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIImageView's userInteractionEnabled is false by default, switch it to true